# Prevent accidental deletes from BigCommerce API

Tags: php, bigcommerce

I am trying to build a feature to delete a BigCommerce store product using the DELETE request.

The syntax for this is:

```
DELETE /api/v2/products/{id}
```

The syntax to delete all products in the store is:

```
DELETE /api/v2/products
```

So, if we do not specify the product {id}, there is a possibility of deleting all products in the store. I do not want this to happen at any cost.

Apart from checking for a NOT NULL id value, is there a way to completely block the **"delete all products"** request in the API?

Comment: I am 99% certain that you should contact the BigCommerce support team for this request.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is requesting tech support.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not currently a way of preventing or blocking this request on a per store basis. This is a change BigCommerce would have to make, however, there is the limiting factor of having to have a basic auth API token or oAuth credentials.